# Qt6.5.0. Сборка помимо .exe файла генерирует lib<target_name>dll.a файл

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, build

собирал Qt6.5.0 из [исходников](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/releases/tag/v6.5.0). Компилятор: mingw13.2.0 posix seh msvcrt [брал здесь](https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds-binaries/releases/tag/13.2.0-rt_v11-rev1)
Cmake: 3.28.20231208-g39b9808
Ninja: 1.11.1

Выполненные шаги:

1. `configure.bat -static -static-runtime -release -qpa windows -c++std c++17 -cmake-generator "Ninja" -accessibility -no-pch -linker lld -opensource -confirm-license`
2. `cmake --build . --parallel`
3. `cmake --install .`
4. Создал проект Qt Widgets в Clion:
   CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "D:/qtBuilds/6.5.0posix-seh-msvcrt/lib/cmake")

find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS
        Core
        Gui
        Widgets
        REQUIRED)

add_executable(untitled main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(untitled
        Qt::Core
        Qt::Gui
        Qt::Widgets
)
```

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QPushButton button("Hello world!", nullptr);
    button.resize(200, 100);
    button.show();
    return QApplication::exec();
}
```

После сборки данного проекта, в директории `cmake-build-debug` помимо `untitled.exe` создаётся файл `libuntitled.dll.a`. Заметил, что он создаётся, если в команде `target_link_libraries` есть `Qt::Widgets`. Если оставить только `Qt::Core` и `Qt::Gui`, то после сборки данный файл не создаётся. На ПК (`Win11 23H2 x64`), где собираю проект, exe-шник запускается и без этого файла в директории, а на другом ПК (`Win10 x64`) при запуске возникает ошибка: [image: This app can't run on your PC. To find a version for this PC check with software developer.]

Почему данный файлик создаётся и как можно попробовать исправить данную проблему?

Comment: Непонятно, чем вам мешает этот файл, cmake помимо него создает кучу мусора. А если вопрос про проблему с запуском, то его и стоило указывать в заголовке.

Comment: @user7860670 , он мешает мне тем, что без него на другой машине программа не запускается, поэтому хочу разобраться, почему он генерируется.

Comment: *"без него на другой машине программа не запускается"* - ¿Как вы пришли к такому выводу? В вопросе же написано *"exe-шник запускается и без этого файла в директории"*. Собственно `.a` файлы - архив с объектными файлами, который при работе программы вряд ли используется. А на другой машине скорее всего не запускается, так как там библиотек-зависимостей нет.

Comment: @user7860670 Я просто перенёс получившуюся программу на другой пк с такой же архитектурой (x64) , в ожидании, что она запустится (правда ОС разные). Но получил такую ошибку (скриншот в вопросе), затем я решил, дай-ка я ещё и этот .dll.a файл положу рядом с exe. После этого программа завелась. Если не хватает библиотек - зависимостей, при запуске ведь возникает ошибка о нехватке какой-то .dll-ки, например, программе не удалось найти libstdc++-6.dll и т.д. В моём же случае такой ошибки не возникает.

Comment: Об этом стоило сразу написать в вопросе. ¿А что лежит в этой .dll.a?

Comment: @user7860670 [Скриншоты](https://imgur.com/a/Xe874FJ), вот что такое qt_startup_hook-и ничего не смог выяснить.

Comment: Стоит посмотреть [dependency walker](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies/releases/tag/v1.11.1) зависимости, которые тянет за собой приложение.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ спасибо за совет! [скрин с зависимостями](https://imgur.com/a/2I81rC9), как только убрал из папки с компилятором libwinpthread.dll, то появляется ошибка о её нехватке. На втором пк по этому пути точно ничего нет... Странно, что на нём не показывает такую ошибку. С ходу как-то не вышло их статически слинковать :) Нужно попробовать использовать win32 вариант вместо posix. Должно помочь, как попробую, я отпишусь о результатах.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ получилось, взял компилятор версии win32, а не posix. Пересобрал qt, Добавил в CMakeLists.txt set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-static -lpthread"). Теперь программа запускается на другом пк без ошибок. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Будет классно, если сможешь оформить здесь это ответом. [Самоответы тут приветствуются.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6300/176217)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась путём сборки qt компилятором, с thread model=win32 и добавлением в CMakeLists.txt строки `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-static -lpthread")`.